# Kali Linux stays on the black screen on boot and the graphics look weird

Tags: linux, kali-linux, system-installation

I'm trying to install Kali Linux on my laptop, but I'm having a problem with the boot screen. When I say load in graphic mode, a black screen is displayed, and the strange images appearing in the picture appear and nothing happens. I think this error is related to the graphics driver or chip. I am trying to do this setup with the USB disk. I tested the USB disk on my desktop computer and the installation starts. As I thought, Kali Linux seems to be a problem with the graphics component embedded in my laptop. Does anyone have any ideas? How can I solve this problem? You can review the photos below to understand me better. Thanks in advance.

**My System:**
**Lenovo Thinkpad T430
Intel Core i5 (3rd Gen) 3320M / 2.6 GHz
8 GB DDR3 SDRAM/1600 MHZ
Intel HD Graphics 4000**

> For more info go link about T430;

https://www.cnet.com/products/lenovo-thinkpad-t430/

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Daily reminder that Kali Linux is a horrible choice for a daily driver/main OS and installing it to a harddrive should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: I will not use it as the main operating system. I'il install it on an external drive. Besides, I want to ask you something else. Now, with my bootable USB disk, KAli Linux operating system starts directly. Can I use it this way? Any problems?

Comment: Yes, you can use it this way. However, if you don't have persistence enabled, all modifications to the system will be lost once you reboot.

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem with Debian Buster (Kali is based on it, as far as i know), however when i turn BIOS from UEFI mode to "both" the boot screen of grub looked differently and i was able to install system with graphics mode
later i've changed bios back to UEFI mode and installed grub-efi as is described here: https://askubuntu.com/a/509564